# Founding father/mother or founding figure?

Tags: word-usage, academia

I'm quoting an author who is known as the "founding father" of a scientific discipline. However, I feel that I want to make it sound less patriarchal. Of course, many disciplines had women leaders, but I have seldom heard "founding mothers". I was wondering if it would be better to talk about influential people in these disciples as "founding figures" than "founding fathers/mothers"?

Comment: Hello, Typer. Is there any sign that 'founding figure' is at least a reasonably close collocation?

Comment: You're onto a good idea not exclude women in the assumption that founders are men. However, your male author founding father is not at fault for being a man.

Comment: Why not just “founders”?

Comment: If he's known as the 'founding father' I guess it's not up to you to re-brand him. No doubt it's the assonance of the two f's that gives 'founding father' its appeal. ('She was the masterminding mother...') But you could call him 'the founder' and such people 'founders'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but I'm voting to close as this is not a settled matter of grammar or usage, and any answers will be based primarily on opinion or conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "founder" is the most appropriate gender-neutral term for "founding father".

This and other gender-inclusive terminology can be found in Boston University's guidelines for inclusive language available [here](https://www.bu.edu/brand/guidelines/editorial-style/inclusive-language/).

Comment: If there was more than a single *founder*, it could be *founding* ***member***.